# Prove by induction $\ n^{\log_2(n)} \le e^n $

Tags: induction

prove for any $\ n \ge 1 $

$\ n^{\log_2(n)} \le e^n $

Since both positive for every $\ n \ge 1 $ I was thinking of taking the $\ln $ of each function and then:

$\ln(n^{\log_2(n)}) \le \ln(e^n) \Rightarrow \log+2(n) \cdot \ln(n) \le n$

and for $\ n = 1 $  can see that $\log_2(1) \cdot 0 \le 1 $

the problem is I can't really do much with the function for $ n+1$

$\log_2(n+1) \cdot \ln(n+1) = ? $

can't really transform it to anything else.. I 've also tried taking the $\log_2 $ instead of $\ln $ but still..

Comment: what is the difference between $\ln$ and $\log$ in your notation?

Comment: log base of two

Comment: $\log+2$ is a typo

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to use induction only? Otherwise one can consider the function $f(x)= x-(lnx)^2$ in $x>1$  and see that the function is non-decreasing by using derivative test. Since $x>1$ and $f$ is non-decreasing, hence, $x-(lnx)^2>1>0$. Now take exponential both sides which will preserve the inequailty as exponential is increasing function and then you get the desired result.

Comment: Well, it says using Induction. You can put this as a comment though.

Comment: Yeah, but this problem makes use of various continuous functions and their properties. I can't think of any induction proof that wouldn't implicitly use them.